# Extending Array prototype with a generic function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to add a simple generic function to the Array prototype but TypeScript gives me an error about typings that I don't get.

```
interface Array<T> {
    pluck<T, TKey extends keyof T>(this: T[], key: TKey): T[TKey][];
}

Array.prototype.pluck = function pluck<T, TKey extends keyof T>(this: T[], key: TKey): T[TKey][] {
    return this.map(item => item[key]);
}
```

Here is a Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-3oww1?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Just omit the typings for your function implementation, you already typed it via the interface declaration

Comment: Please put the relevant code in this question, so it can be of use to people in the future when they visit here.

Comment: Dont do that, just create your new Array which will extend original one. In general you should not override any prototypes, and for sure not the core ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you refer to a generic parameter in the interface or class definition, you should not create one in the method. Right now TypeScript is correctly pointing out that `T` coming from `Array<T>` is not the same as `T` coming from `pluck<T`. So if you remove one in the interface definition, everything is fine:

```js
interface Array<T> {
    pluck<TKey extends keyof T>(this: T[], key: TKey): T[TKey][];
}
```